# Как выполнить запрос(фильтрацию) в Access?

Tags: sql, qt

Как отфильтровать по диапазону дат (от и до)?!

Нужен запрос вида [SQL-WHERE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqltablemodel.html#setFilter) (для функции setFilter).

Лог дебага

```
"Дата BETWEEN '01.05.2017' AND '02.05.2017'"
"[Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC Microsoft Access] Несоответствие типов данных в выражении условия отбора."
"QODBC3: Unable to execute statement"
```

Пишу на Qt.

```
void DataBase::DiapasonDate(QTableView *tableView,QString TableName, QDateEdit *Date1, QDateEdit *Date2)
{
  objTable ->setTable(TableName);
//  Date1->setDisplayFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
//  Date2->setDisplayFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  QString queriDiaposon = "Дата BETWEEN '" + Date1->text() + "' AND '"+ Date2->text() +"'";
  qDebug()<<queriDiaposon;
  objTable->setFilter(queriDiaposon);
  if (!objTable ->select())
  {
      qDebug()<<objTable->lastError().databaseText();
      qDebug()<<objTable ->lastError().driverText();
  }else
  {
   tableView->setModel(objTable);
  }

}
```

Comment: В MS Access литералы даты обрамляются не кавычками, а диезами.

Comment: Дата содержит синтаксическую ошибку в выражении запроса 'Дата BETWEEN #01.01.2000# AND #01.05.2017#'."

Comment: В таком случае остаётся предложить только попробовать  использование "стандартного" американского формата времени MM-DD-YYYY.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался нужно было поменять формат типа

```
  Date1->setDisplayFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
  Date2->setDisplayFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

И запрос типа

```
objTable->setFilter("Дата BETWEEN #" + Date1->text() + "# AND #"+ Date2->text() +"#");
```